# was supposed to do/to have done

Tags: meaning

I come across both "be supposed to do" and "be supposed to have done".

For example:

> I was supposed to go to that restaurant to have dinner with him.
>
> I was supposed to have gone to that restaurant to have dinner with
> him.

What's the difference?

I think "He was supposed to have been a coach" can mean "He was believed to have been a coach". But "I was supposed to have gone to that restaurant" must mean something else, or can it also mean "I was believed to have gone to that..."?

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "supposed to" can sometimes be ambiguous; in your two examples, however this is not the case. We can bring this out by stating another: "he is supposed to be here by now", which means that he is *meant to* be here by now, or that he *should* be here by now. But, as you point out, we can also use "supposed" (!not "supposed to") to indicate that this is what was believed, "he was richer than I had supposed", which means that he was richer than I had *believed* or *thought*.

Sometimes we can totally lose the meaning in sentences like "journalists are supposed to be politically neutral", where it could mean either 1) journalists are often thought to be politically neutral, or 2) journalists should be politically neutral. In cases of this ambiguity one has to use context to work out the intended meaning.

Comment: "I was supposed to go to that restaurant to have dinner with him, but I really didn't feel like travelling into town." (Refers to a plan that existed on a day in the past.) "I was supposed to have gone to that restaurant... but I never got there because my car broke down." (Refers to a plan made in the past that, we now know, didn't happen.)